# How to update query params in Socket.io connection?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Does anyone know if it's possible to update socket.io query params without disconnecting/reconnecting?

Also if having to reconnect is the only way to update query params, is there an elegant way besides socket.disconnect(), followed by socket.connect(); ?

This is currently my solution (which seems very inelegant):

```
socket.io.opts.query = {
          session_id: sessID,
          access_token: _data.access_token,
};
socket.disconnect();
socket.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend breaking the connection first, and only then changing the data:

```js
socket.disconnect();
socket.io.opts.query = {
          session_id: sessID,
          access_token: _data.access_token,
};
socket.connect();
```

Second, your `session_id` and `access_token` fields are used on the server to authenticate the user, and you can send a request (`emit`) to update this data without breaking the connection. And after this you clean old user data and init new user data on your server. This solution is also not elegant, but it will avoid breaking the connection, which is more important in my opinion.

Example:

**Client side**

```js
socket.emit('relogin', {
  session_id: sessID,
  access_token: _data.access_token,
});
```

**Server side**

```js
socket.on('relogin', async ({ session_id, access_token }) => {
  relogin(session_id, access_token); // update user data
});
```

P.S. Sorry for the delay in answering. I also touched on this issue and decided to write here about my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **

> forceNew: true

** in the connection string.